# Dealing with data clashes on the portal server

Tags: java, portlet, websphere-portal

I read in the [this article](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/JSR-286-development-tutorial-Data-clashes-and-encoding-namespaces) that if we have 2 portlets, both render a jsp where say a textbox name is `userName`. When we enter "test" in the textbox of one of the portlets, then if we have something like this in the `doView` method:

```
String userName = request.getParameter("UserName");
```

then `userName` of both the portlets will have the value test.

I know when we call processAction as a post method then `doView` methods of all the portlets in the portal page are called.

For some reason, this does not happen for me as in the `userName` of both the portlets does not have the value "test". Only the one that invoked the post method has the value "test".

I am using IBM Websphere portal 8.0

```
   <FORM method="GET" action="<%=renderResponse.createRenderURL()%>">

 <INPUT name="<%=QuickSearchPortlet.FORM_TEXT%>" type="text"/>
        User Name: <input type="text" name="UserName"/>
 <INPUT name="<%=QuickSearchPortlet.FORM_SUBMIT%>" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        <input type="file" name="imageFile">
  </FORM>.
```

doView() method of multiple portlets: String userName = request.getParameter("UserName");

Answer (score 0):

Per the portlet spec, you need to do:

```
Map userInfo = (Map) request.getAttribute(PortletRequest.USER_INFO);
String givenName = (userInfo!=null)
15 ? (String)
userInfo.get(PortletRequest.P3PUserInfos.USER_NAME_GIVEN) : “”;
String lastName = (userInfo!=null)
? (String)
userInfo.get(PortletRequest.P3PUserInfos.USER_NAME_FAMILY) : “”;
```

Comment: I think my question was a little unclear, I am not looking to get the userinfo in here. What my question was that would 2 portlets will have the same value for variable "userName" even though the post method of only one portlet was called. So essentially since both the portlets are rendering a jsp page that have a text box that is named userName will effect in the way the value is retrieved in the doView method.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mentions it as

```
request.getParameter("UserName");
```

which means it is part of the request you would submit every time. The request that you are submitting is for the portlet for which the action method is being invoked. The other portlets would merely be invoking the doView method. If the other portlets also refer to the userName as `request.getParameter("UserName");`, then obviously, the value is not getting submitted to them.

If you would want the username available across portlets, either you have to do inter-portlet communication or share the attribute in session if it is the same value across the other portlets. Also, did you try debugging the doView() methods of other portlets to see if they are invoked or not?

Comment: Yes the doView method of other portlets are getting invoked. I am aware of the inter portlet communication. I am not trying to achieve that here, what i am trying to do here is to reproduce an issue that comes up when you don't use namepsace while setting the name of the text box for eg and while retrieving the value of the text box which in my case is userName. If you read this article http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/JSR-286-development-tutorial-Data-clashes-and-encoding-namespaces which is short you will know exactly what i am trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Sachin,

If I understand you right, you are trying to call processAction of a portlet, and expecting the parameter be available in doView of all portlets?

If you are submitting to the processAction(using actionURL in form action), only the target portlet's processAction will be called. Then the portal container calls the doView of all portlets. 
When doViews are called, the parameters are not transferred from processAction to doView. So you wouldnt see the parameter in any of the doViews.

Edit: If you are submitting to the doView from a form(using renderURL in form action) - I'll have to test this scenario will try it out next week.

Note: Normally you don't submit a form to render phase as you are not supposed to change the portlet state in reder phase. - [refer to this also](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014238416)

Please provide your jsp form code and portlet controller code to give you more accurate answer.

Comment: mgill this is exactly what i was trying to use. i am new to stckoverflow(posting code) so i have pasted my jsp and doView method logic in original post where I had posted my question.